# Identity function not working in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Emp with columns as

```
EID     Name      Salary     City
```

I have added `Identity(1,2)` to my column `EID`.

I was expecting an output of 1,3,5,7 .... for my auto incremented EID column.

But I am always getting seed value for ID starting from 9

eg- 9,11,13....... as my EID values.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I don't know the reason for this, but you also don't really need to know this.  The contract of an identity column in SQL doesn't guarantee what the starting value might be, only that each generated value will be unique, and that values will tend to increase as they are generated.

Comment: @Sami `(1,3)` would provide the values 1,4,7,10... not 1,3,5,7....

Comment: Did your table have rows in it before, even if you inserted those rows and since deleted them by using `DELETE`? Perhaps that's causing your seed to start at a different point. When you `DELETE` a row is doesn't cause the `IDENTITY` value to "rollback". If you're deleting all the rows, and want to reset the identity you need to use `TRUNCATE`. If you're not, and (as a one off) want to reset the value you need to use [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Uniqueness of `identity` values is *not* guaranteed. it's quite easy to insert a record with an identity value that already exists in the table. Also, when resetting the identity values using `dbcc checkindent`, as [this script demonstrates](https://rextester.com/ERX39551)

Comment: @ZoharPeled But uniqueness should be guaranteed for _autogenerated_ values, right?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, auto-generated values should carry no business meaning. That is true for both identity values and guid values generated using `newId()` or `newSequentialId()` You should just let the database handle them and slap on a unique constraint to ensure uniqueness

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you don't mess with it manually, AFAIK identity values will be unique. However, personally I never trust that. Given the fact that too many developers have access to my databases I'm always using identity only as a surrogate key and therefor the primary key of the table (which, as you know, is unique by definition)

Comment: `DELETE` would not reset identity. Try `TRUNCATE TABLE...` and then insert a few records to see you get `1,3,5,7,...`.